# Using a JComboBox in java for a time delay in a GUI

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jcombobox

I am trying to set up a drop down menu in GUI which will set different time delay. My problem is that i am not familiar with JComboBox or GUI for that matter. So far i have(see below) my thought process is that i will have the drop down menu set up and when the user selects a particular setting. that number will change the  "DELAY_MILLIS" which then would change the Thread.sleep. there is already other code to set up the GUI i just need to add the drop down menu for it.

```
enter code here

JComboBox<Integer> comboBox = new JComboBox<>();  

comboBox.addItem(50);
comboBox.addItem(250);
comboBox.addItem(750);
comboBox.addItem(1500);



private static int
    DELAY_MILLIS =  50 ;

private void delay() {
    try {
        Thread.sleep(DELAY_MILLIS);
    }
    catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: `my thought process is that i will have the drop down menu set up and when the user selects a particular setting. that number will change the "DELAY_MILLIS"` - sounds reasonable. Try it and see how it works.

Comment: For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).